# QucsStudio: Unknown variable

Tags: simulation, error, qucs

I'm using QucsStudio4.3.1 to simulate a voltage divider circuit.
Everything is fine until I try to plot the result.

The tutorial shown like below

[image: Result shown from tutorial]

[image]

But the result I got is like

[image]

Missing a properties from a "battery"(V1.I)

Even I tried to manually type it in the blank of "Graph Properties", it just shown "Unknown variable 'V1.I'."

[image]

Below is my circuit and tutorial's

[image: My circuit]

[image: Tutorial's circuit]

I have followed the rules of available dataset items

[image]

Could someone point out where the problem is?

*Reference - A Tutorial Getting Started with Qucs Page 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial uses Qucs and not Qucsstudio.

In Qucsstudio you must add an current probe to make this measurement.

[image: screan simulation]